# How can a programmer know whether he has to program a method or search for it in a library?

Tags: programming-practices, libraries, third-party-libraries

I am a beginner programming in Java. And when confronted with a new task I wonder whether I should code the function or search for it.

For example, if I want to calculate 10!, or cos A, I reckon that there will be a math function somewhere, and I am better off searching for it instead of trying to code the function.

But what if it's something more exotic? How can I know whether I should invest my time searching or coding?

Comment: The same way all the rest of us do it: you make a good faith effort at finding the math function online, balancing the amount of time it takes to search against the amount of time it takes to write your own function.  Also relevant: https://xkcd.com/1205/

Comment: Taking 20 minutes to search for someone having done something equal or similar to what you need will almost always be worth it. Even if the solution you find doesn't exactly match your needs, it will give you valuable insights into the problem domain that will help you when you write your own solution.

Comment: If you are learning from a textbook, sometimes the answer will be different from what you would do "in the real world". For example, maybe you were supposed to code the factorial function on your own in order to understand how to make a recursive function. If you used a predefined implementation, you may have missed the point of that lesson.

Answer (score 7):

1. [Search the official Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/search.html).
2. No luck there? Then go to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and enter `[java] Thing I want to do` into the search bar. The most upvoted answer to the first question you find will likely contain how to do it either using the standard library or by doing it yourself.
3. No question like that? Maybe someone just described it differently. Try to paraphrase your search query using different words. Or use Google instead. When you add `site:stackoverflow.com` to your Google search query, you only get results from stackoverflow. Google search is often far superior to the built-in search function of many websites, including StackExchange.
4. Even Google can't find anything helpful on Stackoverflow? Congratulations, it seems like you managed to find something still not mentioned in over one million Java questions. This is about as likely as getting struck by lightning while winning the lottery. Time to write a new question.
5. Stackoverflow can't or won't help you? Then it seems you *really* found an unique and complex problem which you will have to solve on your own.

Comment: I would like to add to 4: "if it is the first time you write a question on SO, please make sure you meet their basic quality standards for questions - read their FAQ, look which kind of questions are getting up- and downvoted/closed for which reasons. Try to write a good, understandable question, providing some context of your goals and what you already tried".

Comment: There are also type-driven search engines such as [Hoogle](https://www.stackage.org/nightly/hoogle?q=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Bb%5D) for Haskell, [Merobase](http://merobase.com/) and [SEA-QL](http://seambase.com/products.htm) for Java. Also, [Test-Driven Code Reuse](http://swt.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/en/research/archive/research-areas/software-reuse/test-driven-reuse) using [CodeConjurer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/code-conjurer) for Java or [pytest-nodev](http://pytest-nodev.readthedocs.io/) for Python

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit more to it than just finding a library.

Let's say you want factorial. Common sense says that factorial is quite standard, so there is quite a high chance of finding something.

Then, you have things which are not that standard, but can be done quite easily from standard pieces. For example, assuming the tangent wasn't a standard operation, you can search for a library that has sin and cos and use those to compute the tangent.

But usually you don't think this much whether there is a library or not. This is actually quite easy to find on google. What is a bigger problem, and perhaps a more relevant question, if you should use another library or not.

Basically, a new library is another dependency to worry about. Different programming languages and projects have different way of dealing with this, but the problem still remains: is it worth adding a huge library in the list of dependencies of the project just for a small function? Is there a smaller, better suited library? And, probably even more important, how well supported is the library? What are the chances of it being abandoned?

Answer (score 0):

First, search for an existing function in the java library.  Especially if you're a beginer, you should never hesitate to do this, because it's the best way to memorize the many available solutions that are out there, and the structure of the libraries. For example, no need to reinvent [cos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) :-)

Next search if there are some [well known library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/utilities.html) to do it.  If yes, have a look at them.  For common problems, there are chances that some people have explored this extensively, have produced better code than you will and have tested their solution a number of times.

Then have a look at some less known libraries, if it appear to solve your case easily.  For example, even if [factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/891059/3723423) is easy, there is a lot of optimization already done. But if they prove to be too complex to learn or if you have doubts about quality, write the code.  But have fist a look in order to see if there are some of these libraries that cover frequent problems in your specific case.

Fortunately, nowadays you have Google or DuckDuckGo that significantly accelerate this exploratory process !

Answer (score 0):

When writing Java, I've sometimes found methods or even entire frameworks to solve my problems much later. This does not matter and it does not make me sad, I have to say, because I learn how to write it myself. And there is also a possibility that the API uses much more abstractions than you actually need.

I invest a lot of time to look up classes and then their methods in the Java API if I don't already know them. It is not wasting time, by the way, because on your way you learn new things and next time you know about the existence of these things that you've already seen. Programmers have usually a good memory.

If I have given up to look for it in the API, I look at other things in my favorite search engine by using carefully chosen keywords. And if I don't see any results that solve my problem, I usually stop searching except if the problem is hard. Then I invest more time, because it's worth to spend time on it.

Also the longer the time you need to find a solution, the more probable it is that the solution will be of low quality (assuming that your keywords you chose were good).

Conclusion: searching for APIs and parts of solutions is not a lost time. This is a part of a learning process. And even if you missed a good solution and implemented some other solution by yourself, it is (in most cases) not catastrophic.

Answer (score 0):

My general rule.  Time required is key.

Make your decision based on which is quickest.

Writing a small function that's easy to code, test and debug may be quicker than a search.  If the function is complex or lengthy, it will likely be quicker to search for a well tested function than to test and debug your own code solution.